# Changed URL, but Event and Contributions modules not recognizing the change

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

Hope someone can help me.

I changed the URL, the directories and server are the same, and I still keep the old domain as well.  I have changed the directories, cleaned the cache and followed the instructions for moving the server (even though I did not change servers, only the Domain name).

Everything works fine, the url address is the new address and all the links work great, until I go to an Event and someone tries to register. Once the person clicks on 'register here' the url goes back to the old one.  What setting am I missing???

In the contributions the same thing happens it does not recognize the new domain and it goes back to the homepage with the old URL.

For example,  I am in

http://NEWDomain//index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/info&Itemid=146&reset=1&id=59

Once I click Register it goes to

http://OLDDomain/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/register&Itemid=146&id=59&reset=1

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you changed your URL in the CiviCRM user interface, but perhaps not in your civicrm.settings.php file. In that file you will need to look for and adjust your CiviCRM Base URL to the new domain.

Comment: Excellent, you're very welcome. Could you mark as answer? Thanks!

Comment: So sorry for the confusion, Jennifer! I didn't know the proper term, and I think that messed us up here.  Turns out the official term is 'accept' the answer.  My bad. :-)  Please review this link real quick, http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, and accept my answer and delete the thank you answer.  Thanks!